# NavigationView with a NestedScrollView inside does not fling

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I have a NavigationView with a NestedScrollView that contains another NavigationView for the purpose of adding a footer for the NavigationView. The layout code is as follows:

```
<include layout="@layout/main_content"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView ...>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        ...
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            ...
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                ...
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
                app:menu="@menu/nav_menu">
            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/spacer_to_bottom"
                ...
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </LinearLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/nav_footer"></include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Check the full code here: https://github.com/MarcDahlem/AndroidSidemenuFooterExample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

The problem is that the scrolling in the NavigationDrawer is not smooth (does not "fling"). In other words, it scrolls while your finger is on the screen and stops when you remove your finger.

I tried disabling nested scroll for the first child (the LinearLayout) of the NestedScrollView but this didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try it android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"  inside nested scrollview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigations I realized that the first child of the navigation view is a RecyclerView. Disabling nested scrolling on that view resolves the issue

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(navigationView.getChildAt(0), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to handle this nested scroll that is;
if you are using nestedscroll view, and using one or more list views/recycler views inside it, we have to enable this;
yourlistview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

It should work now.